# How can I commit with no fast forward option (--no-ff) in SourceTree?

Tags: macos, git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'd like to preserve merge commits even if there was no change in the originating branch since than.

Is there such an option in [Atlassian SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/)? I just can't find it at the first sight.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Ahh, got that. There is a "Do not fast-forward when merging, always create commit" option in preferences.

[image]

Comment: Note that the Windows version of SourceTree actually provides this option right in the merge dialog. Weird that the OS X version wouldn't `:/`

Comment: Actually `--no-ff` should be the default behaviour I think in `git`.

Comment: @Cupcake I've logged this for you here: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-2350 We had a discussion about it, and the Windows one makes more sense in terms of being the most common use case. You'll have to wait until 2.0 though ;)

Comment: Hey thanks! Awesome product by the way. OFF: You may consider a feature where you can hide specific branches from the graph view. Simply a checkbox above every branch. Just an idea came across here yesterday.

Comment: @KieranSenior hey cool, thanks. By the way, I sent some random complaint tweets to the [SourceTree twitter account](https://twitter.com/sourcetree) a week or two ago, which weren't very fair and helpful. I've since deleted them, you guys can just ignore them. Sorry.

Comment: @Geri If you could file an issue that'd be great. My inbox is usually flooded with various requests so it's difficult to manage :)

Comment: @Cupcake It's better to be vocal than to keep quiet sometimes, don't sweat it, we love hearing feedback regardless of how offensive or not it may seem :)

Comment: I just +1'ed on that JIRA task. This implicit auto-FF behavior is quite confusing to GIt noobs.